# AngularJS Link function not called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write my first AngularJS directive: one involving the `link` function.  The directive is being loaded, but when I use it in my page the `link` function is not called.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jCUSh/115/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="biApp">
    <google-maps-symbol></google-maps-symbol>
</div>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
var appModule = angular.module('biApp', []);

appModule.directive('googleMapsSymbol', function () {
    console.log("Directive was run");
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log("Link was called");
        }
    };
});
```

I'll bet I'm doing some simple thing wrong.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The default for angular is to assume that directives are `attributes`, not `elements`! You are using a directive as an element so you need to specify this with the restrict. The updated code reads:

```
appModule.directive('googleMapsSymbol', function () {
    console.log("Directive was run");
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log("Link was called");
        }
    };
});
```

Note the `restrict: 'E',`. Best of luck!

**Updating your fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/j8ZZ4/

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  The reason I was confused is that if I removed the `<google-maps-symbol>` element from my fiddle, the first `console.log` statement was not executed.  So it looked like Angular was interpreting the element as a directive like I expected.  It all makes sense now.

Answer (score 5):

It is not your case, but the same issue might occur when the naming of your directive is not correct. **Be especially careful to dashes in the name**. Since angular *automagically* transforms between them, it's a very very common mistake.

consider this template

```
<div>
  <div this-wont-work></div>
  <div this-will-work></div>
</div>
```

with this directives.

```
 angular
   .module('biApp')
   .directive('this-wont-work', () => ( { link: () => console.log('nope')} ))
   .directive('thisWillWork', () => ( { link: () => console.log('works')} ))
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a different problem: an `ng-include` in the same element was trying to include an empty string (`""`) and so didn't let the directive `link()`, for some reason.

By having a page available in the `ng-include`, the `link()` was called as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason this could happen for people is that there is a runtime error in one of the other compilation phases for the directive.

```
ng.module(MODULE).directive('myDirective', [() => {
    return {
        link() {
            // Never getting here
        },
        template() {
            // Error here would mess things up
        },
        controller() {
            // error here would mess things up
        }
    };
}]);
```