# AngularJS Link function not called due to attribute name normalization

Tags: angularjs

I've defined a validator by following the documentation under Custom Validation at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms.  But for some reason the `link` function isn't getting called.  I can tell it's not getting called because the log message doesn't appear.

HTML

```
<textarea name="topic1Data" ng-model="inputCtrl.inputValues.topic1Data" rows="10" cols="30" required hasHeaders></textarea>
```

JavaScript

```
inputForm.directive('hasHeaders', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            console.log("Evaluating hasAtLeastAHeaderRow validator");
            ctrl.$validators.integer = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
                    // consider empty models to be valid
                    return true;
                }

                if (INTEGER_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
                    // it is valid
                    return true;
                }

                // it is invalid
                return false;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Others have reported the same symptom but the cause of my problem seems to be different:

- [Link function not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160356/link-function-not-called)
- [AngularJS Link function not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412000/angularjs-link-function-not-called)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by naming it `has-headers` in the HTML and `hasHeaders` in the JavaScript:

HTML

```
<textarea name="topic1Data" ng-model="inputCtrl.inputValues.topic1Data" rows="10" cols="30" required has-headers></textarea>
```

JavaScript

```
inputForm.directive('hasHeaders', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            console.log("Evaluating hasAtLeastAHeaderRow validator");
            ctrl.$validators.integer = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
                    // consider empty models to be valid
                    return true;
                }

                if (INTEGER_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
                    // it is valid
                    return true;
                }

                // it is invalid
                return false;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Here, I think, is the relevant documentation about AngularJS custom directive naming conventions:

> **Normalization**
>
> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine
>   which elements match which directives. We typically refer to
>   directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g.
>   ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

Source: ["Normalization"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)